# Do dependencies affect the bundle js size?

Tags: performance, webpack, optimization, bundle

I'd like to know one thing.
Let's assume I add the npm package in the package.json file and don't use it anywhere in the code. In this case do the unnecessary dependencies affect the bundle js size?

Answer (score -1):

Webpack dont read or use package.json at all. So obvios answer is "No".